# Erro 1215 com chave estrangeira

Tags: laravel

Estou trabalhando meu primeiro relacionamento de tabelas one to one no Laravel para países e localizações, criei os models e os migrate para as duas tabelas.

Tabela de Países:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

E a tabela de localizações:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('latitude');
        $table->integer('longitude');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('country_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('countries')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Executei o comando `php artisan migrate` para importar as tabelas no banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que é retornado é o `erro 1215`, abri o phpMyAdmin e fui no desenhador do banco de dados e conferi que realmente o relacionamento não foi criado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Voltei na função up() do migrate e defini o tamanho do campo para 20 caracteres para ver se era esse o problema e executei o comando `php artisan migrate` e o erro persistiu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui contornar o erro, alterando as instruções do migrate Locations para:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
        $table->integer('latitude');
        $table->integer('longitude');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('country_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('countries')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: Exatamente, os tipos das colunas não batiam.